# Lost in Pokemon Alpha Sapphire Delta Episode after not playing for months

Tags: pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

I stopped playing ORAS after I'd beaten the Elite 4 last year as I went overseas. I've started playing again and the last thing I remember doing is watching the rocket think at Mossdeep Space Centre.

Thing is I'm kind of stuck as I want to finish the Delta episode so that I can get to the Battle Resort. I've looked at 3 or 4 different walkthroughs and have tried to pinpoint at what point I'm up to in the Delta episode by going to various places along the steps, but nothing is happening. I don't have the SS tickets so I'm assuming I haven't finished the episode (and I haven't caught Rayquazza).

Could anyone possible help me figure out where I'm up to? This is driving me mad!

- I have one of the Johto starters from the professor

  - Its the only thing I could progress with by myself and that was an accident.
- I can't find my rival, Wally, Stephen, or any of Team Aqua.

Here's what I've done following the guides for the Delta episode:

1. **Littleroot Town** - Tickets are in inventory
2. **Petalburg City** - Fairly sure I've done this, can't find Wally or Admin Matt, and I think I remember getting the phone call off Stephen.
3. **Rustboro City** Fairly certain I've done this too. The Devon CEO just has a generic speech dialogue.
4. **Granite Cave** - Zinnia's not there.
5. **Mossdeep City** - Meteorite shard is *not* in my inventory, and I can't enter Mission Control. It's guarded by a woman saying "I'm sorry, we're in the middle of something and I can't let you upstairs." No Team Aqua grunts around.
6. **Meteor Falls** - I've explored the whole falls including the top area with Waterfall/Surf. No one is at the very top where I'm meant to find Stephen.
7. **Rustboro City** - No Team Aqua/Scientist trigger when I try to enter Devon Corp.
8. **Mossdeep City** - Same for Space Center
9. **Team Magma/Aqua Hideout** - Zinnia and the admins aren't there. Just wander through nothing happens no one battles
10. **Mossdeep City & Route 131** Wallace isn't at the Cave of Origin's entrance, and not at the Sky Pillar entrance. Sky Pillar has the regular guard.

Comment: Try visiting the Devon Corp in Rustboro City. Throughout the Delta adventure, the CEO on the top level reminds you several times where you should head.

Comment: @Mortaza This would make a good answer

Comment: I've been here and spoken to everyone from the company including the CEO, who says "Since my youth, I've immersed myself in work. Consequently, I'm not very familiar with recent trends and that sort of things. Do all young people want to be trainers and aim for the Pokemon League, I wonder?". I'll add some details of whats happening so maybe that will give more insight to the question :)

Comment: @Mortaza Any suggestions guys? I've been trying all day again and am still lost.

Comment: You documented everything pretty well, so no sorry. If I were you, I would google-backtrack from the entrance of the Sky Pillar. Eg, 'How to enter Sky Pillar', then if you can't do those steps, google how to do those steps. At least you have a point in time to reference to.

Comment: I know this is old, but to help out other people who find this answer: If you don't have Meteorite shard and Devon CEO isn't telling you where to go next, then it seems like you haven't triggered the early events in The Delta Episode yet.

Answer (score 2):

Try heading into your Rival's house (the house opposite of the one you moved into in the beginning of the game).

Worked for me when I was in the exact same situation as you.